# Linux network namespaces as regular user C

Tags: c, linux, networking, namespaces, privileges

In linux you can create network namespaces, using the `ip` command. But you need to be root to run that command. However you can still create network namespaces as a regular user:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sched.h>

unshare(CLONE_NEWUSER | CLONE_NEWNET);
```

. With this command, the new network namespace will be owned by a restricted user namespace.

With a new network namespace i can't connect to internet. Creating a veth pair requires root, is there a way to allow my network namespace to connect to the internet without root? And create that network namespace with C. I know that many features like sharing the physical network with the namespace would not be possible. Can you create virtual interfaces like `tun0` in a restricted network namespace.